# If I am using postGIS, should I store lat and long columns if I am already storing a geometry column?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, geolocation, postgis

I am using postGIS and my clients will send me a `lat,lng` for geolocation points.

I am storing these points in my database as `GEOMETRY` in a `geometry` column.

Now, I have a need for clients to receive points back and I am wondering if it makes sense to store the `lat` and `lng` in addition to `geometry` so that each time I don't have to use postgis function to calculate the point out of the geometry, especially for lists of entities that have points.

Comment: The missing question is if you are willing to handle/propagate a change in the geometry or in the long/lat values.

Comment: If you need fast access to nearby(nearby of any type) points, definitely should, otherwise not.

Comment: How are you delivering points back to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends on what your application does with the coordinates. If you don't need to perform any sophisticated operation with these points, having them as numeric values in separated columns should suffice - numeric indexes are quite efficient.

But, what are the advantages of using `geometry` or `geography` data types?

- Coordinates are based on a certain [`SRS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system), which can be encoded with the the geometry values - WGS84 assumed if information omitted. In case your clients are using unusual reference systems, there is no way of knowing that by just seeing two numeric values. See [`ST_SRID`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SRID.html).
- PostGIS offers ~1.3k functions that are really handy, such as [`ST_Distance`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Distance.html) or [`ST_DWithin`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) and has an efficient [`spatial index`](https://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html).
- Publish geometries using applications like [`GeoServer`](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html) via OGC standards like WFS (Web Feature Services) or WMS (Web Map Service).
- Easily import data into GIS, such as [`QGIS`](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/de/docs/training_manual/databases/db_manager.html) or ArcGIS.

I'd argue that using `geometry` or `geography` data types is almost always the best choice, but in case all above mentioned features are irrelevant, one could use numeric values. In your case I would stick to the `geometry` data type and provide the x,y coordinates using PostGIS functions, just like you're doing now.